# Why ({}+{}).length equal to 30?

Tags: javascript

## {} to String?

Anyone can tell me why this is 30?

```
({}+{}).length //  = 30?
```

But this is 0?

```
([] + []).length //  = 0?
```

Comment: Because `({}+{})` = `"[object Object][object Object]"` and `([] + [])` = `""`

Comment: But `({} * 2).length` is undefined :)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Thank you

Comment: @manonthemat Yeah, that's because `+` is addition *and* string concatenation.

Comment: @manonthemat That's because you're multiplying an Object by a number and then getting the length, so that will always be undefined because an Object can't be multiplied.

Comment: You can do `2 * [1]` to get `2`, but `2 * [1, 2]` returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 11):

This is the expected behavior. When you use the `+` operator on 2 arrays, both arrays are cast to a string, which is basically the same as calling `.join(',')`. If the arrays are both empty, you will get two empty strings concatenated, resulting in one empty string which has `0` length.

```
([] + []) = ""
```

However with objects, the way they are cast to a string is different. By default, the `+` operator will cast the objects to strings, which will result in the string `"[object Object]"` Do that twice, and you will get a `30` character long string.

```
({}+{}) = "[object Object][object Object]"
```

Comment: JavaScript can be so weird.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator in Javascript is used to add Numbers or Strings, but when used on an Object it essentially calls the `toString` prototype.

So: `({}).toString()` is `[object Object]`

And, if you add two strings together that are `[object Object]`
You get: `[object Object][object Object]`, thus the length is 30.

But an empty array `[]` to a String is just `""`, so two `""`'s combined is still just: `""`, thus the length is 0.

`([]).toString() // -> ""`